# Dojo Charts: Stacked Columns Labels

Tags: charts, dojo

I'm having some problems with labels inside stacked columns and I would like to know if you have some sort of tip for a new Dojo user!

After a lot of research, I found a fiddle example that shows exactly what I want! As you can see in the example above (Sorry, sof does not allow me more than 2 links), the labels are written inside their own Stacked Column, placed in the middle with no label 'hacks'.

In my code, I tried to follow all the documentation instruction but all I can get is this:[my attempt to make it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Gre.png)

```
chart1.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
            type: StackedColumns,
            lines: true,
            areas: true,
            markers: true,
            labels: true,
            labelStyle: "inside",
            fontColor:"white", 
            gap: 5,
        });
```

After some code customization, I got the following result: [my second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrL5.png) As you can see, this might work, but it won't for a different data set.

```
chart1.addPlot("stackedColumnsPlot", {
            type: StackedColumns,
            lines: true,
            areas: true,
            markers: true,
            labels: true,
            labelOffset: -35, 
            labelStyle: "inside",
            fontColor:"white", 
            gap: 5,
        });
```

I'm also having problems when I have 10 columns side by side, in this case, my labels dissapear. On google chart, the own library handle this issue by writing the label outside and drawing a small line to connect with the column.

The Dojo Charts documentation is very handy but it's not as specific as my boss need. Can someone pitch an idea of how to manipulate this labels in a much more customized way? THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: the fiddle link i described above is http://jsfiddle.net/sunman/B45PW/

Comment: What version of dojo are you using? If you change in linked fiddle version to > 1.10.8 you'll get similar issue as in your case - it may be worth to report it.

Comment: I prefered to go to another aproach, changed the library usage from dojo to charts.js. Dojo is really great, but I beleave the charts library could be much much better. I would be nice if dojo incorporate the charts.js to their project. Thanks to all!